# Imac Snow Leopard Startup disc issue

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

I inherited my late father's Imac and successfully installed Snow Leopard via install DVD. I am now in the process of trying to restore the system in order to dispose of it. However, not being able to find the original disc that shipped with the system, I attempted to use Snow Lion which I cloned onto a USB flashdrive, to reboot the computer in order to restore.
When I boot, it opens on Mac OS X Installer window. Prompted to select a startup disc 2 images appear - network startup and my hard drive image named "Mac OS X Install DVD". Restarting and returning to the Installer, I am asked to Select where I want to install the Mac OS. The only disc image is the flashdrive with the cloned Mac OS showing the yellow "!" logo. The only option is to "Go Back" to the previous installer prompt to again select the startup disc.
Any suggestions as to how to get my original hard drive image to appear on the startup disc selection? Disk Utility does not allow repair or restore of the hard drive when it's selected.

Comment: Problem solved.

Comment: You're allowed to answer your own question. You should either post how you solved it or delete the question.

Comment: Solution: Fortunately, I have a hard time throwing away aged Macs and I remembered that my daughter's old iBook G4 with OS X 10.5 was buried in a safe place. Used TDM, designating the iMac as the target, and then used Disk Utilities to clone the iBook HD to the iMac, after which I was able to install OS X 10.6 onto the cloned HD.

Comment: Post the solution in an Answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
Posted the fix as a comment when it should have been in the answers post. here it is...
```

Solution: Fortunately, I have a hard time throwing away aged Macs and I remembered that my daughter's old iBook G4 with OS X 10.5 was buried in a safe place. Used TDM, designating the iMac as the target, and then used Disk Utilities to clone the iBook HD to the iMac, after which I was able to install OS X 10.6 onto the cloned HD. – Mikey K yesterday